# We are trying to establish 2 way SSL connection. getting handshake error. log attached

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, sslhandshakeexception

I have added certificates in my keystore and trust store and then trying to call the https endpoint using spring boot.  Getting the below log. Not able to understand much on the ssl log .. hence asking some help from the community.

SSL log in debug mode:

```
[OUT] http-nio-8080-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80

[OUT] http-nio-8080-exec-4, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

[OUT] http-nio-8080-exec-4, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure

[OUT] %% Invalidated: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]

[OUT] http-nio-8080-exec-4, called closeSocket()
[OUT] http-nio-8080-exec-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: Does the endpoint support TLS 1.2?

Comment: Yes it supports 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is fixed. Actually the SSL context that was set through spring was unable to send the client certificate during the handshake and the reason I found is that my Keystore pwd was different than private key password. Though during keystore loading through spring, I provided correct pwssword for both still it could not able to extract the certificate based on the private key password.

Resolved after I provided same password for both keystore and private key during the key generation process.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why they even provided private key passwords. They are not at all well supported.